# 2001 Pontiac Grand Am - Oil in coolant

Tags: oil, troubleshooting, coolant, pontiac, grand-am

I just bought my car from a owner I noticed there was oil or what looks like oil in the coolant there is no coolant in oil and car doesn't over heat. It's a 2001 Pontiac Grand Am with 230,000 miles please help

Comment: Not that it matters too much, but which engine I4 or V6? Also, when you say there is oil in the coolant, how much? Is there just skim of oil, or is the whole thing muck?

Comment: Maybe  post a pic if you can.